# How to display video progress/toolbar in TextureView that is playing a video

Tags: android, video, android-video-player, android-videoview, textureview

Brief background: I've attempted to take a screenshot/capture of a streamed video that is playing inside of a VideoView. After a lot of research, I've found that this is not possible. The recommended way is to play a video using a MediaPlayer through a TextureView and simply use getBitmap() to produce the image.

The downside is that the TextureView no longer displays the default video playback UI bar (play, pause, progress, FF/RW). How can I bring this back into a TextureView? Is there a default API?